# Performing Laplace transform on non-continuous function in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I am calculating the following function's Laplace transform, but I get some strange output with `limit` and `realpart` etc on `(%t5)` and `(%t6)`. What I expect is something like `a_n = 0` and `b_n = -1/(n*%pi)`.

Why is this happening? Am I defining the function at `(%i1)` incorrectly? Or is this a limitation of Maxima?

[image: function plot]

```
(%i1) f(t) := mod(t, 1);
(%o1)                          f(t) := mod(t, 1)
(%i2) plot2d(f(t), [t, -2, 2]);
(%o2)                 [/tmp/maxout1266174.gnuplot_pipes]
(%i3) load(fourie);
(%o3)         /usr/share/maxima/5.43.0/share/calculus/fourie.mac
(%i4) fourier(f(t), t, 1);
                                         1
(%t4)                               a  = -
                                     0   2

                    /
                    [
(%t5) a  = limit    I cos(%pi n t) realpart(floor(t)) dt
       n   t -> - 1 ]
                    /
                                           /
                                           [
                                  - limit  I cos(%pi n t) realpart(floor(t)) dt
                                    t -> 1 ]
                                           /

                     /
                     [
(%t6) b  = (- limit  I sin(%pi n t) realpart(floor(t)) dt)
       n      t -> 1 ]
                     /
             /
             [                                      2 sin(%pi n)   2 cos(%pi n)
  + limit    I sin(%pi n t) realpart(floor(t)) dt + ------------ - ------------
    t -> - 1 ]                                           2  2         %pi n
             /                                        %pi  n

(%o6)                           [%t4, %t5, %t6]
(%i7)
```